# Reflexive Closure Matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to determine the matrix that represents the reflexive closure of the matrix provided. I'm a little (a lot) confused on how reflexive closure works - could someone point me in the right d[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRaIa.png)irection?

Comment: Do you know which entries absolutely must be $1$ in order for the matrix to represent a reflexive relation?

Answer (score 0):

The reflexive closure of a relation just adds any missing elements of the form $(x,x)$.

That ensures the relation is reflexive, and does so in a minimal way.

In the matrix representation, that would put a $1$ in every diagonal location.